# testng and PowerMockito: class not prepared exception

Tags: java, testng, powermockito

I am trying to write a unit-test on a static class. I actually want to verify that a method on that class is called.

```
@Guice(modules = testModule.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServiceRunnerBase.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class RunnerTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceRunnerBase.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStopCallsReleaseLock() {
        // I will add code here when I get the powerMockito mockStatic to work.
    }
}
```

My test compiles, but when I run it, I get this exception:

```
    org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 

    [Ljava.lang.Object;@2fb38899
    The class ServiceRunnerBase not prepared for test.
```

However, my class is in the `@PrepareForTest` annotation. My class `ServiceRunnerBase` is an abstract class, but it has several static methods defined in it. I cannot change `ServiceRunnerBase`.

ServiceRunnerBase is an abstract class, with the following (I cannot post the code, it is proprietary)

- private static members, some marked with `@Getter`
- static methods, some private, some protected and some public
- The method that I am trying to verify that my code is calling is

  - protected static void release(String callingClass, final boolean success)

What am I doing wrong with PowerMockito?

Comment: can u post the ServiceRunnerBase class also

Comment: @Mark are you missing `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` ?

Comment: @RunWith is for JUnit, I am using testng

Comment: I cannot post the ServiceRunnerBase class, it is proprietary. I will add some description of it in my question.

Comment: `ServiceRunnerBase` is not final right?

Comment: abstract class ServiceRunnerBase

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test and configuration for abstract class and working fine. Let me know if you have different powermock verison

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Production Class

```
public abstract class SR {
    protected static void release() {

    }
}
```

Test Class

```
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.SR;

@PrepareForTest(SR.class)
public class TSR extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SR.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStopCallsReleaseLock() {
        // I will add code here when I get the powerMockito mockStatic to work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here after running into the same issue. I am also using TestNG.

I noticed an autocomplete error in my test. My IDE auto imported org.junit.Test instead of org.testng.annotations.Test when I typed @Test. This caused my test to run as JUnit and to not understand the TestNG specific configuration for PowerMock.

Check your imports and make sure JUnit didn't sneak in there.

My test worked after I straightened all that out.